# How to save in temp using coding

Tags: python, odoo

the other day, I have asked how to store the data that we fill in the field A also appears in the field B. I've found, but the problems that arise.
this my code

```
def _compute_dept(self, cr, uid, ids, deposit, available, arg, context=None):
    result = {}
    for r in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
       avail=0
       if r.deposit:
            avail = r.deposit
            print avail
       result[r.id] = avail
    return result
_columns = {
    'name': fields.many2one('res.partner','Partner'),
    'date':fields.date('Date of Deposit'),
    'deposit': fields.float('Deposit'),
    'available': fields.function(_compute_dept, type='float', method=True, store=True, string='Available', readonly=True),
    'note': fields.text('Description'),
}
```

but the problems that arise. If I type in the field A "10" then the field B also appears "10", but when I type it again in the field A "20" then the field B appears "20" .. well, it should show 30, because 10 + 20. So how to keep the number 10 in the coding temp. that the field B show the number 30

P.S : field A is deposit and field B is available

Comment: What fields? I don't see any fields in your code.

Comment: what you mean ? so here. the point when the field B (available) there are number 20. and the added number 10 on the field A (deposit) the results of the field B is 30

Answer (score 1):

You should change your design.

You need a `bank_account` with many (many2one) `deposits`. Then create an `available` function field in the `bank_account` model.